# Why no reputation for good comment?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, comments, reputation

We should also encourage good comment, since not everyone is willing to write a long detailed answer, they may provide thoughts which is also very important. Also comment is the start of a deeper discussion, so I think we should encourage a little bit of good comment by giving some reputation to the corresponding person who writes a voted up comment.

Imagine the loss of some great points by the some people who may think the question is not worthwhile to write an answer, or they are too busy or too lazy to do so.

Comment: There is, of course, the [Pundit](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/24/pundit) badge.

Comment: Note also that lots of times, highly voted comments are irrelevant and/or witty remarks. I do not think these should be rewarded, as they do not contribute to anything.

Comment: @KyleKanos Yes, some humorous comments

Comment: @EmilioPisanty do you know of any way to track down which comments of mine were upvoted? I'm curious!

Comment: @Danu try the Badge Progress thread  on the mother meta. If there's a way you must be able to find it via your Pundit progress.

Comment: I'm a little surprised to see this so downvoted.  I came to physics meta looking for an answer to this exact question, and would have asked it if I hadn't found it.  Perhaps the answer is obvious to experienced users.  Doesn't make it a bad question.

Answer (score 12):

We are *not a forum*, but a question and answer site. It is not the aim of the SE model to encourage debate, but to provide (more or less) definite answers to definite questions. Though comments may contain worthwhile information, reputation is granted for contributions towards good questions and answers.

Comments are transient by design, and subject to deletion at any time. They are not made to stay, and should not be used to state vital information - everything that is crucial should be edited into the existing questions and answers, or be written into another answer. Making comments grant reputation disincentivizes good edits and answers, which is contrary to the goal of creating good Q&As.

Comment: “Comments are transient by design, and subject to deletion at any time.” Even no reputation ,why comment is subject to deletion? I've seen many comments very helpful, sometimes contain points more critical than the answer.

Comment: The valuable material from comments of that kind should be edited into posts to insure that it is preserved. Comments exist for exactly one reason: to allow side discussion that lead to improved posts. Other kinds of side discussion happen (quite a lot on Physics SE) but they are living on borrowed time.